# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - Cant map data from axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

In react, I am trying to fetch data from an API call which I have created. The console prints out the correct response which is list of names of users, but the mapping is not working for me. Any advice would be beneficial.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";

const CreateProject = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("Choose option");
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { label: "Loading", value: "Loading" }
  ]);
  const onSubmit = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // initialise as false
    let unmounted = false;
    async function getUsers() {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/findUser/findUser"
        // Api for finding user
      );
      const body = await res.data;
      console.log(res.data);
      // check state is still false beofre state is set
      if (!unmounted) {
        setItems(
          body.res.map(({ name }) => ({
            label: name,
            value: name
          }))
        );
        setLoading(false);
        // setLoading allows change to option - data displayed
      }
    }
    getUsers();
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="ProjectName"
        name="ProjectName"
        ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 20 })}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Project Details"
        name="Project Detail"
        ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })}
      />
      <select
        disabled={loading}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
      >
        {items.map(({ label }) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {errors.search && <p>No user found</p>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreateProject;
```

The error I receive is seems to be around the body.res.map at setItems - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: So "The console prints out the correct response which is list of names of users" means `res.data` is an array, right? Then you are using it like `body.res` which basically means `res.data.res`. Which makes no sense since you said `res.data` is an  array.

Comment: Can you share `res.data` value for us, to find out if it does contain another `res` property on it or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually console logging other variable than what you're mapping over.
If what you're logging is the right thing, your `setItems()` should be:

```js
setItems(
   res.data.map(({ name }) => ({
      label: name,
      value: name
   }))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`const body = await res.data;` There is no reason to write `await` because `res.data` is not a promise.

Here's how it should be `const body = res.data`

And in this block you need to map only body

```
setItems(
   body.map(({ name }) => ({
       label: name,
       value: name
          }))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promise chaining instead of await to make things smoother

```
 async function getUsers() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/findUser/findUser")
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
                if (!unmounted) {
                    setItems(
                        res.data.map(({
                            name
                        }) => ({
                            label: name,
                            value: name
                        }))
                    );
                    setLoading(false);
                    // setLoading allows change to option - data displayed
                }


            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    }
```

Comment: Appreciate it thank you! The only thing that stops it now is "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" which is probably the render method which needs checking

Comment: Will you please give an example?

Comment: "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." That's the warning I receive but I can still use the values. And I believe it is the way I am iterating through the items.map in the select type inside the return.

Comment: try setting key={label}